# Facebook Connect for iPhone - want to log in and post in one step

Tags: iphone, facebook

This is a repost from the Facebook developer forums, where no-one has responded yet.

This is what I would like to do:

- user touches Connect button
- code retrieves session and attempts to resume
- if session does not resume, pop up login dialog
- pop up feed dialog (after user has successfully logged in)

What actually happens in the case where a login is needed:

- user touches Connect button
- login dialog comes up (but user never sees it)
- feed dialog immediately comes up on top of it
- feed dialog spins forever because it is unable to connect

There doesn't seem to be a way to use the delegate methods to tell if the user has finished logging in;  dialogDidSucceed never seems to be called for the login dialog.  For that matter, there doesn't seem to be a way to tell if they cancelled out either (in which case going on to the feed dialog would be pointless).

Am I attempting the impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While [Ed's answer is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579083/facebook-connect-for-iphone-want-to-log-in-and-post-in-one-step/1580224#1580224), he's not explaining why.

When you send the show message the first dialog, it shows, but doesn't wait for it to close.. the program execution moves along to the next line. Therefore you are asking the next dialog to show, which it does – right on top of the previous one. This is true for dialogs or alert views on the iPhone platform.

Ed's answer is showing the first dialog but not continuing. What is not obvious, is that when the user successfully logs in, the session delegate is sent the `-didLogin:` message. You may have expected a dialog delegate message?

Be careful though, as other situations that you code may result in the session login, and it will run the code in the delegate method.. and you may not want that!

An example of this is when the session resumes. To keep it straight-forward, assume you have two actions in your app, and both publish a short story to the user feed. When you ask the user to login – or resume – their existing session, the session delegate message `-didLogin:` will be sent. You need to make sure your implementation of `-didLogin:` handles both situations, and both actions.

*As an aside, consider using the latest SDK and the `stream.publish` request, or the `FBStreamDialog` class (instead of `FBFeedDialog`)for pushing the story to facebook.*

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I understood what was wrong with my code but not how to fix it, and the pointer to the session delegate is what I needed.  I had thought that both the login and feed dialogs would implement the dialog delegate but the login one doesn't.

I'm not sure I understand your last sentence, though.  What sort of situation would trigger the session login without them actually having logged in?

Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, I get it now.  I was just looking at FBStreamDialog... wish they had provided a bit more detail, but I'll figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void) login {
  session = [FBSession sessionForApplication:... secret:... delegate:self];
  FBLoginDialog *dialog = [[[FBLoginDialog alloc] initWithSession:session] autorelease];
  dialog.delegate = self;
  [dialog show];
}

- (void) session:(FBSession *)newSession didLogin:(FBUID)newUid {
  session = newSession;
  uid = newUid;

  FBFeedDialog* dialog = [[[FBFeedDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
  dialog.delegate = self;
  dialog.templateBundleId = ...
  dialog.templateData = ...
  [dialog show];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(I'm "answering my own question" because this was too long to leave as a comment on the previous entry)

I don't think I explained the problem clearly enough... let me try again. The code below is executed when the user touches the "share on facebook" button:

```
// get session
if (session == nil) {
    session = [FBSession sessionForApplication.....];
}
// log in if necessary
if (![session resume]) {
    FBLoginDialog* dialog = [FBLoginDialog alloc...];
    [dialog show];
}
// post feed story
FBFeedDialog* dialog = [FBFeedDialog alloc...];
dialog.delegate = self;
dialog.templateBundleID = ...;
[dialog show];
```

This does not work, for obvious reasons - both dialogs come up right away.  While I see that splitting it into two methods would help, the main problem is that I have nothing on which to trigger bringing up the feed dialog.  dialogDidSucceed doesn't seem to get called for the login dialog, and there doesn't seem to be anything else I can look for.  Most apps split this into two buttons, meaning the user has to touch a second button in order to initiate posting a feed story.  I was hoping to avoid that, but I can't find a way to do it.